# Which way of the cast between str and int is faster in Python?

Tags: python, performance, casting, python-3.5

Let's say I have a few numeric variables that will be used throughout the code like `int` and `str` objects. So I'm wondering, which type should I use to store them?

Here's an example:

```
class Nums:
    a = 1  # stored as int
    b = '2'  # stored as str

print(int(Nums.b) + 5)  # 7
print(str(Nums.a) + 'Hello') # 1Hello
```

As you can see, there are the two choices of storage and example uses. But the usage won't be so defined like it is here. For example, I will iterate over the class variables and concatenate them all in a string and also compute their product. So should I store them as `int` and cast to `str` when I need concatenation or as `str` and cast them to `int` before multiplication?

Some brief research using the IPython's `%timeit` has shown that the performance is about the same, `int` to `str` is a tiny bit faster:

```
In [3]: %timeit int('56')
The slowest run took 12.92 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 360 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit str(56)
The slowest run took 8.36 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 353 ns per loop
```

And I would expect this result, as an `str` call really just calls the object's `__str__` method, while reading a string as a number could be more complicated. Is there any real difference and what's the reason behind it?

I'm talking about Python 3.5 particularly

Comment: We're talking about a few ns it's really not worth the discussion imho

Comment: @sirfz yeah, it's not like these ns will make a huge difference in my program, but the question here is more about the better storage practice. What's more efficient and why, regardless of how much efficiency we actually get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program uses numeric values, you should certainly store them as type `int`.  Numeric types are almost always faster than string types, and even if your use case means the string representation is faster, the other benefits are worth it.  To name a few:

- You get sanity checks for free.  If someone tries to shove "five" into your program, if you're storing as integers you'll get an error early.  If you're storing as strings, your error may be much harder to reason about.
- Anyone picking up your program will expect numeric values to be stored as numeric types
- And again, storing things as numeric types is almost always faster

Comment: That's the thing, my program uses both the numeric values and their string representations for string operations. What do you mean by "storing things as numeric types is almost always faster"? Is the object access faster or what?

Comment: Yes.  Strings are stored as objects, and require an extra dereference to get to the character array.  Integers don't have this overhead.